# Defining std::vector::push_back(new Object)

Tags: c++, vectors, coordinate-system

Is this the best way to construct a vector of 2D points for return?

I don't entirely understand `new` and `delete` so I'm concerned about any memory leaks that I might be incurring.

```
std::vector<Point2D> results;
results.reserve(max_results);
```

... inside a loop /

```
Point2D* point = new Point2D(x, y);
results.push_back(*point);
delete point;
```

It might be that I could do this without constructor.

```
class Point2D {
public:
    double X;
    double Y;
    Point2D();
    Point2D(double X, double Y);
    void set(double X_p, double Y_p);
    void set(Point2D* point_p);
};
```

Comment: NO: Do `results.push_back(Point2D(x,y));` If you have C++11 use `results.emplace_back(x,y);`. In normal day to day code the use of new/delete should be rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The variable and function names should be lowercase since the types are uppercase.  This would allow for more distinctive naming.
- In `Point2D`, both `X` and `Y` should be `private`.  This applies to all data members.
- If you don't need the default constructor for `Point2D`, leave it out.
- There's no need to allocate memory for `point`; just construct a local object:

  ```
  Point2D point(x, y);
  ```

  There should be as little manual memory management in C++ as possible.

Comment: Thank you Jamal. When is manual memory management (`new` and `delete`) actually needed?

Comment: @ColeLawrence: Usually when you're writing a data structure, such as a linked list.  Even then one may use smart pointers instead (which manage their own memory), but not always.

Comment: In addition to this great answer try to create immutable objects. Objects with setters have the tendency to create objects with invalid state,

Answer (score 3):

You are over complicating the class:

```
class Point2D {
public:
    double X;
    double Y;
    Point2D();
    Point2D(double X, double Y);
};
```

Since your memebrs are public you don;t need a specific `set()` just use the constructor to update both points at the same time.

This should cover it:

```
int main()
{
    Point2D   point_A;        // default initialized
    Point2D   point_B(5,4);   // A specific point.

    point_A = point_B;        // Copies over.
    point_B = Point2D(8,9);   // Move to another point.

    point_B.X = 22;           // Update X


    std::vector<Point2D> results;
    results.push_back(Point2D(11,0));  // Create a point and copy into result.
    results.emplace_back(44, 5);       // Get the vector to create the point using
                                       // the constructor.
}
```

Alternatively you can use `std::pair` (assuming by your comments you are just using this as a bag of values).

```
// Replace your class with.
typedef std::pair<double, double>   Point2D;

int main()
{
    Point2D   point_A;        // default initialized
    Point2D   point_B(5,4);   // A specific point.

    point_A = point_B;        // Copies over.
    point_B = Point2D(8,9);   // Move to another point.

    // The difference between std::pair
    // and your orginal class is the name of the members.
    // in std::pair the member names are  `first` and `second`
    point_B.first = 22;           // Update X


    std::vector<Point2D> results;
    results.push_back(Point2D(11,0));  // Create a point and copy into result.
    results.emplace_back(44, 5);       // Get the vector to create the point using
                                       // the constructor.
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I might take this approach instead since I'm basically using the class solely for holding values x and y.

Comment: @ColeLawrence: There is a utility class for just holding a bag of two things. Its called `std::pair`.